# Access Denied for Rooms API

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to fetch the rooms data from another organization. For that, I have successfully generated the JWT token by giving almost all permissions by **A organization** for the particular user and also created the Login URL for the consent with all permissions. And accepted permissions for the **B organization**.

But when I try to fetch the rooms API from the **A organization** user it throws, access denied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you actually mean by "organization" but if you are referring to a DocuSign account, then this is not allowed. You cannot use one account context to get information from another account. You would have to change the authorization, permission, and consent to be for the same account from which you're trying to get information.

Comment: Thank you @Inbar Gazit, In that case, I want to create an Integration key for that account to retrieve the data?